# Mongo convert Document to DBObject

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

Hi I need to convert Mongo Document to DBObject (BasicDBObject).

I am uploading a file to mongo using GridFS and I want to set metadata, which I get in document. I know Document is pretty much the same as DBObject. I know I can do something like this:

```
Document doc = new Document();
BasicDBObject.parse(doc.toJson());
```

But isn't this needlessly performance heavy?

The gridFS method `setMetaData()` accepts only `DBObject` so i have to convert it.

Is there a better way of doing that rather then converting it to string and back ?

Comment: *isnt this needlessly performace heavy* why do you believe so?

Comment: It's actually kind of odd and seems more of an oversight that the type has not been updated here. However the simple answer is of course it's just a `Map`, and as such behaves just like any other.

Comment: Ok maybye its not performance heavy but at least it seemed pointless for me to convert it to string ant than back.

Comment: This is the only way it will work if you have embedded documents. Accepted answer won't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are kind of micro-optimizing here.

However, since both classes are implementations of Map, you can just do:

```
Document document = new Document();
BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject(document);
```

Internally this does a `Map#putAll` operation that puts all entries of the Document map into the BasicDbObject map.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question and there is an accepted answer however it is not correct.

The proposed answer only does a **shallow** conversion between `Document` and `DBOject`. If your Json object contains nested objects or lists they will not be converted properly.

I got around this problem by serialising to JSON string. It is not efficient at all but might be enough in most cases, and at least it is correct:

```java
public final class BsonConverter {
    public static Document toDocument(DBObject dbObject) {
        return Document.parse(dbObject.toString());
    }
    public static DBObject toDBObject(Document document) {
        return BasicDBObject.parse(document.toJson());
    }
}
```